# What is the maximum time that any javascript file can take to execute in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, scripting

Will Javascript  has time  constraints on  execution time in  browsers, when I add `<script>` tag in my webpage ?
Will browsers forcefully  stop Javascript if it takes more time ?

Will  all  browsers have same maximum run time ?

Comment: Browsers do give users a way to stop javascript which is blocking the page for too long.

Comment: So what exactly are you running that might be taking forever to process? There might be better solutions to prevent it from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a definitive "maximum time" a JavaScript file can take to execute in a browser, as this largely depends on the performance of the browser, the complexity of the JavaScript code, and the capabilities of the user's device.

Answer (score 0):

There's no specification/standard for that, could vary from a browser to a browser, a version to a version